# JQuery UI Datepicker Stuck

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

We have a custom coded JQuery UI datepicker that allows elements to be taken and submitted to an availability form. The issue is that the form is constantly locked to show the 30th of September, I have set the current date variable back as far as may this year and the dates before are clickable but the month will not change showing august and september with september 30th greyed out and the rest clickable. Currently it is pulling the current date on the site so nothing is clickable but still stuck on the 30th of september display.

Website: https://www.chestnuttholidayparks.com/

[Image of date set to may this year](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CzNUc.png)

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="current_date"><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>-</div>

            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    if (!String.prototype.startsWith) {
                      String.prototype.startsWith = function(searchString, position) {
                        position = position || 0;
                        return this.indexOf(searchString, position) === position;
                      };
                    }

                    if (!$('#date').hasClass('options_button_deactive')) {
                        start_date_check = $('.current_date').text();

                        start_date_check = start_date_check.split('-');

                        start_date_check_year = start_date_check[0];
                        start_date_check_month = start_date_check[1];
                        start_date_check_day = start_date_check[2];

                        start_date = $('#booking_form > .content > form > #park > .options_wrapper_holder > .options_wrapper > .label_selected').children('.start_date').text();
                        start_date = start_date.split('-');

                        start_date_year = start_date[0];
                        start_date_month = start_date[1];
                        start_date_day = start_date[2];

                        if (start_date_check_year > start_date_year) {
                            start_date_year = start_date_check_year;
                            start_date_month = start_date_check_month;
                            start_date_day = start_date_check_day;
                        } else if (start_date_check_year == start_date_year && start_date_check_month > start_date_month) {
                            start_date_year = start_date_check_year;
                            start_date_month = start_date_check_month;
                            start_date_day = start_date_check_day;
                        } else if (start_date_check_year == start_date_year && start_date_check_month == start_date_month && start_date_check_day > start_date_day) {
                            start_date_year = start_date_check_year;
                            start_date_month = start_date_check_month;
                            start_date_day = start_date_check_day;
                        }

                        if (start_date_day.startsWith('0')) {
                            start_date_day = start_date_day.substr(1);
                        }

                        start_date_day = parseInt(start_date_day, 10);

                        if (start_date_month.startsWith('0')) {
                            start_date_month = start_date_month.substr(1);
                        }

                        start_date_month = parseInt(start_date_month, 10);

                        end_date = $('#booking_form > .content > form > #park > .options_wrapper_holder > .options_wrapper > .label_selected').children('.end_date').text();
                        end_date = end_date.split('-');

                        end_date_year = end_date[0];
                        end_date_month = end_date[1];
                        end_date_day = end_date[2];

                        if (end_date_day.startsWith('0')) {
                            end_date_day = end_date_day.substr(1);
                        }

                        end_date_day = parseInt(end_date_day, 10);

                        if (end_date_month.startsWith('0')) {
                            end_date_month = end_date_month.substr(1);
                        }

                        end_date_month = parseInt(end_date_month, 10);

                        $("#date .datepicker").empty();
                        $("#date .datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker');
                        $("#date .datepicker").removeAttr('id');

                        selected_date = $('#input1').val();
                        if (selected_date != '') {
                            selected_date = selected_date.split('/');

                            default_month = selected_date[0];
                            default_day = selected_date[1];

                            if (default_day.startsWith('0')) {
                                default_day = default_day.substr(1);
                            }

                            default_day = parseInt(default_day, 10);

                            if (default_month.startsWith('0')) {
                                default_month = default_month.substr(1);
                            }

                            default_month = parseInt(default_month, 10);
                        } else {
                            default_month = start_date_month;
                            default_day = start_date_day;
                        }

                        $("#date .datepicker").datepicker({
                            minDate: new Date(start_date_year, start_date_month - 1, start_date_day),
                            maxDate: new Date(end_date_year, end_date_month - 1, end_date_day),

                            //dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                            defaultDate: start_date_year+'-'+default_month+'-'+default_day,

                            numberOfMonths: [1,2],
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input1").val());
                                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input2").val());
                                return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
                            },
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input1").val());
                                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input2").val());
                                var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

                                if (!date1 || date2) {
                                    $("#date #input1").val(dateText);

                                    get_dateText = dateText.split('/');
                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);

                                    $("#date #input2").val("");

                                    $('#EDay').empty().val();
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val();
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val();

                                    $(this).datepicker();
                                } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {
                                    $("#date #input2").val( $("#date #input1").val() );
                                    $("#date #input1").val( dateText );

                                    get_dateText = dateText.split('/');
                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);
                                    $('#EDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);

                                    $(this).datepicker();
                                } else {
                                    $("#date #input2").val(dateText);

                                    get_dateText = dateText.split('/');
                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);
                                    $('#EDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);

                                    $(this).datepicker();
                                }

                                date1 = $('#date #input1').val();

                                if (date1 != '') {
                                    date1 = date1.split('/');

                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(date1[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(date1[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(date1[2]);

                                    date1 = date1[1]+'/'+date1[0]+'/'+date1[2];

                                    $('#arrival').addClass('mobile_date_button_selected');
                                    $('#departure').removeClass('mobile_date_button_selected');
                                }

                                date2 = $('#date #input2').val();

                                if (date2 != '') {
                                    date2 = date2.split('/');

                                    $('#EDay').empty().val(date2[1]);
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val(date2[0]);
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val(date2[2]);

                                    date2 = date2[1]+'/'+date2[0]+'/'+date2[2];
                                    $('#departure').addClass('mobile_date_button_selected');
                                } else {
                                    date2 = '<span class="departure">Depart</span>'
                                }

                                $('#date .options_wrapper_holder').toggleClass('date_open');

                                if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 601px)').matches) {
                                    $('#date .name').empty().append(date1 + ' - ' + date2);
                                } else {
                                    if (date1 != '') {
                                        $('#arrival').empty().append('Arr: '+date1);
                                    }

                                    if (date2 != '') {
                                        $('#departure').empty().append('Dep: '+date2);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    $('#park > .options_wrapper_holder > .options_wrapper > label').click(function(){

                        $('#booking_form > .content > form > #date, #booking_form > .content > form > #arrival, #booking_form > .content > form > #departure').removeClass('options_button_deactive');

                        start_date_check = $('.current_date').text();

                        start_date_check = start_date_check.split('-');

                        start_date_check_year = start_date_check[0];
                        start_date_check_month = start_date_check[1];
                        start_date_check_day = start_date_check[2];

                        start_date = $(this).children('.start_date').text();
                        start_date = start_date.split('-');

                        start_date_year = start_date[0];
                        start_date_month = start_date[1];
                        start_date_day = start_date[2];

                        if (start_date_check_year > start_date_year) {
                            start_date_year = start_date_check_year;
                            start_date_month = start_date_check_month;
                            start_date_day = start_date_check_day;
                        } else if (start_date_check_year == start_date_year && start_date_check_month > start_date_month) {
                            start_date_year = start_date_check_year;
                            start_date_month = start_date_check_month;
                            start_date_day = start_date_check_day;
                        } else if (start_date_check_year == start_date_year && start_date_check_month == start_date_month && start_date_check_day > start_date_day) {
                            start_date_year = start_date_check_year;
                            start_date_month = start_date_check_month;
                            start_date_day = start_date_check_day;
                        }

                        if (start_date_day.startsWith('0')) {
                            start_date_day = start_date_day.substr(1);
                        }

                        start_date_day = parseInt(start_date_day, 10);

                        if (start_date_month.startsWith('0')) {
                            start_date_month = start_date_month.substr(1);
                        }

                        start_date_month = parseInt(start_date_month, 10);


                        end_date = $(this).children('.end_date').text();
                        end_date = end_date.split('-');

                        end_date_year = end_date[0];
                        end_date_month = end_date[1];
                        end_date_day = end_date[2];

                        if (end_date_day.startsWith('0')) {
                            end_date_day = end_date_day.substr(1);
                        }

                        end_date_day = parseInt(end_date_day, 10);

                        if (end_date_month.startsWith('0')) {
                            end_date_month = end_date_month.substr(1);
                        }

                        end_date_month = parseInt(end_date_month, 10);


                        $("#date .datepicker").empty();
                        $("#date .datepicker").removeClass('hasDatepicker');
                        $("#date .datepicker").removeAttr('id');

                        $("#date .datepicker").datepicker({
                            minDate: new Date(start_date_year, start_date_month - 1, start_date_day),
                            maxDate: new Date(end_date_year, end_date_month - 1, end_date_day),

                            numberOfMonths: [1,2],
                            beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input1").val());
                                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input2").val());
                                return [true, date1 && ((date.getTime() == date1.getTime()) || (date2 && date >= date1 && date <= date2)) ? "dp-highlight" : ""];
                            },
                            onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
                                var date1 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input1").val());
                                var date2 = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, $("#date #input2").val());
                                var selectedDate = $.datepicker.parseDate($.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat, dateText);

                                if (!date1 || date2) {
                                    $("#date #input1").val(dateText);

                                    get_dateText = dateText.split('/');
                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);

                                    $("#date #input2").val("");

                                    $('#EDay').empty().val();
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val();
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val();

                                    $(this).datepicker();
                                } else if( selectedDate < date1 ) {
                                    $("#date #input2").val( $("#date #input1").val() );
                                    $("#date #input1").val( dateText );

                                    get_dateText = dateText.split('/');
                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);
                                    $('#EDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);

                                    $(this).datepicker();
                                } else {
                                    $("#date #input2").val(dateText);

                                    get_dateText = dateText.split('/');
                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);
                                    $('#EDay').empty().val(get_dateText[1]);
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val(get_dateText[0]);
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val(get_dateText[2]);

                                    $(this).datepicker();
                                }

                                date1 = $('#date #input1').val();

                                if (date1 != '') {
                                    date1 = date1.split('/');

                                    $('#SDay').empty().val(date1[1]);
                                    $('#SMonth').empty().val(date1[0]);
                                    $('#SYear').empty().val(date1[2]);

                                    date1 = date1[1]+'/'+date1[0]+'/'+date1[2];

                                    $('#arrival').addClass('mobile_date_button_selected');
                                    $('#departure').removeClass('mobile_date_button_selected');
                                }

                                date2 = $('#date #input2').val();

                                if (date2 != '') {
                                    date2 = date2.split('/');

                                    $('#EDay').empty().val(date2[1]);
                                    $('#EMonth').empty().val(date2[0]);
                                    $('#EYear').empty().val(date2[2]);

                                    date2 = date2[1]+'/'+date2[0]+'/'+date2[2];
                                    $('#departure').addClass('mobile_date_button_selected');
                                } else {
                                    date2 = '<span class="departure">Depart</span>'
                                }

                                $('#date .options_wrapper_holder').toggleClass('date_open');

                                if (window.matchMedia('(min-width: 601px)').matches) {
                                    $('#date .name').empty().append(date1 + ' - ' + date2);
                                } else {
                                    if (date1 != '') {
                                        $('#arrival').empty().append('Arr: '+date1);
                                    }

                                    if (date2 != '') {
                                        $('#departure').empty().append('Dep: '+date2);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });

                    $('#booking_form form').delegate('.check_button, .update_button', 'click', function(){
                        $('#park, #accommodation, #date').removeClass('booking_error');

                        <?php
                            perch_content_create('Booking Form Settings',array(
                                'template' => 'booking_errors.html',
                                'shared' => true
                            ));

                            perch_content('Booking Form Settings');
                        ?>

                        $('#alert .button').click(function(){
                            $('#alert').removeClass('open');
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This example may contain a bit too much detail. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Couple of points: 1. linking to your site is of no use as, one assumes, your site will change (when this is fixed) making the question useless.  2. `.delegate()` was deprecated over 8 years ago - use `.on`.  3. is your "custom coded" datepicker a normal datepicker with the code you've pasted here or other customisations (in which case it's a datepicker with options, not a custom datepicker).  4 Does the datepicker work without all that code?

Comment: Can you create a snippet here on SO that *demonstrates* the problem? (or, at a pinch, a jsfiddle).  Have a read of [ask] and [mcve].